# I am unable to login in snowsql command prompt

Tags: authentication, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

C:\Users\Dell>snowsql -a sp83419.ap-northeast-1 -u kirankumarp
Password:
250003 (n/a): Failed to get the response. Hanging? method: post, url: https://sp83419.ap-northeast-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443/session/v1/login-request?request_id=8248d097-1577-428d-8f3e-f6240768b59a&request_guid=351cafdb-892b-430c-85a0-12487bc697f1
If the error message is unclear, enable logging using -o log_level=DEBUG and see the log to find out the cause. Contact support for further help.
Goodbye!

C:\Users\Dell>

Comment: This may be a stupid question but have you really just posted your account, username and password to a public forum?

Answer (score 2):

The account identifier parameter value `-a` seems to be lacking cloud provider name - aws(?):

```
snowsql -a XXX.ap-northeast-1.<here_cloud_name> ...
```

---

[Connecting via URL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-connect.html#connecting-via-url)

> Account Locator
>
> ```
> https://<account_locator>.<region>.<cloud>.snowflakecomputing.com
> ```